# VUE add a component with JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Can I create/mount a VUE component calling a JS function in a fullyloaded page?

As a async call? Something like:

```
function getComponent(obj){
    return <component parameters="obj"></component >;
}
```

Comment: Yes.  Your example shows JSX which Vue supports in its render function.  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [Vue dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components). What that allows you is to choose which component to load after the original component has loaded. You can do that whenever and however you want to, aka in an async way. You can read more in the [Vue guides](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components). All the code you need is there so won't repost it here again.

Answer (score 0):

*Can I create/mount a VUE component calling a JS function in a fullyloaded page?*

I think you want to load/mount the component in a certain condition and not on page initialization.

If that the case then you can take advantage of lazy-loading and dynamic components:

```
<template>
  //...
    <button @click="activateComponent">Activate component</button>
    <component :is="dynamicComponent" />
  //...
</template>


<script>  
  export default {
     components: {
        MyCmp: () => import('./MyCmp.vue') //lazy loading
     },

     data: () => ({
      dynamicComponent: null       
     }),

     methods: {
       activateComponent () {
         this.dynamicComponent = 'MyCmp'
       }
     }     
  }
</script>
```